# Play Sound in Local Notification from IPod Library

Tags: objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, uilocalnotification, filepath, mpmediaitem

I am doing an Alarm Clock.
and I want to play sound in Local Notification which is present in IPod Library.

I am Putting sound file in notification like this: **localNotif.soundName = @"sound.mp3";**

If i'll get the **Path** of the **sound file** which is in **Ipod Library**, then I'll use that path as notification **Sound**.

but I am getting the path of sound like this: **ipod-library://item/item.mp3?id=-4317287566833819729**

I am not getting how to use this path as **Notification Sound**. If the sound file is less then 30 seconds.

Any Tutorial, Example Code, Link Will be Great Help.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that the sound can not play longer that 30 seconds and must be in application bundle. There for you will not be able to select it from the iPod library.

`UILocalNotification` [`soundName`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009565-CH1-SW8)

> **soundName**
>
> The name of the file containing the sound to play when an alert is displayed.
>
> `@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *soundName`
>
> Discussion For this
>   property, specify the filename (including extension) of a sound
>   resource in the application’s main bundle or
>   UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName to request the default system
>   sound. When the system displays an alert for a local notification or
>   badges an application icon, it plays this sound. The default value is
>   nil (no sound). Sounds that last longer than 30 seconds are not
>   supported. If you specify a file with a sound that plays over 30
>   seconds, the default sound is played instead.

Comment: i edited that one...means i knew that thing but do you know how the Path is used ??

Comment: You can not place a path the `soundName` property, just the name of sound file the in your app bundle. Thus the sound file needs to be in your app when you compile it.

Comment: Thanks for telling. but if the file in iPod library is less then 30 seconds then i think it should be played as notification. but how to get that file that i dont know...

Comment: No, it will not since it is not in your applications bundle. The app bundle is readonly and you can therefor not add any sounds to it. The app bundle is just your app binary and all the files in you project: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AccessingaBundlesContents/AccessingaBundlesContents.html